# The find array method returns undefined, but only when called from a specific function

Tags: javascript, node.js, find

I am currently learning Node.js by making a mock webshop and have run into a weird bug. In my model I have a function that returns the product that matches the ID that is passed in as a parameter. **The problem is that it returns a different answer when exactly the same parameters are passed in, depending on the function that calls this function in the model.**

This is the method in the model:

```js
module.exports = class Product {
  static findById(id, cb) {
    getProductsFromFile(products => {
      console.log(typeof id, id, products)
      const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
      console.log(product)
      cb(product);
    });
  }
}
```

The *getProductsFromFile* method is a method that returns an array with products from a JSON file. This one works consistently.
The functions in my controller that gets the right answer is:

```js
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.params.productId
  Product.findById(prodId, product => {
    res.render("shop/product-detail", {product: product, pageTitle: product.title, path: "/products"})
  })
}
```

and the other one that gets undefined:

```js
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId, product => {
    Cart.addProduct(prodId, product.price);
  });
  res.redirect('/cart');
};
```

Under here I have added the console logs from the findById method when being called from the first function:

```
string 0.9099787732666649 [
  {
    title: 'A title',
    description: 'A description',
    image: 'http://placehold.it/300x300',
    price: '25',
    id: '0.9099787732666649'
  },
  {
    title: 'Another title',
    image: 'http://placehold.it/300x300',
    description: 'Another description',
    price: '20',
    id: '0.7404003153545062'
  }
]
{
  title: 'A title',
  description: 'A description',
  image: 'http://placehold.it/300x300',
  price: '25',
  id: '0.9099787732666649'
}
```

And here is the result when being called from the second function:

```
string 0.9099787732666649  [
  {
    title: 'A title',
    description: 'A description',
    image: 'http://placehold.it/300x300',
    price: '25',
    id: '0.9099787732666649'
  },
  {
    title: 'Another title',
    image: 'http://placehold.it/300x300',
    description: 'Another description',
    price: '20',
    id: '0.7404003153545062'
  }
]
undefined
```

As you can see the product constant is not defined even though the same parameter is passed in. I feel like I am missing something very obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

I hope that anyone of you knows what the problem is. Thanks in advance for taking a look at my code

Comment: You could maybe try logging `id.length` as well. You might have some extra whitespace in that value. Also try logging the char codes with `[...id].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))` to make sure you don't have any unexpected characters, like something else that looks like a dot.

Comment: Hmm, actually, if the logs you posted *are* accurate, I think you *do* have extra space at the end of `id` in the second case. In the first log there is a single space between these: `0.9099787732666649 [` in the second, there is two spaces `0.9099787732666649  [` which would mean that `id = "0.9099787732666649 "`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use callbacks, what you are doing is a sequential task finding a product from products. If you have anything which is async in nature you should use `callbacks`, but I strongly suggest you to use promises to do such things in future.

Make a simple change in below code:

```
module.exports = class Product {
  static findById(id, products) {
      const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
      console.log(product)
      return product
  }
}
```

In `getProductsFromFile` and the places where you are using above function change this:

```
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const {productId} = req.params
  const result = Product.findById(productId, product);
  res.render("shop/product-detail", {product: result, pageTitle: result.title, path: "/products"})
}
```

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const { productId } = req.body;
  const result = Product.findById(prodId, product => {
    
  });
  const addedProduct = Cart.addProduct(productId, result.price); // make it promise based if async 
  res.redirect('/cart');
};
```

I am sharing a [link](https://jsmanifest.com/promises-in-javascript/) that can help you understand when to use what.

Comment: I suspect `getProductsFromFile` is asynchronous based on the name and the callback it takes. EDIT: also your simple change completely eliminated `getProductsFromFile`

Comment: But `getProductsFromFile ` this is not being used anywhere in the code as it is not being returned by the function. It seems he is just adding extra layers of code to do the task. He can use promises that can be a better way to achieve it. Don't you think so ?

Comment: "*But getProductsFromFile this is not being used anywhere in the code.*" it is a function that is called in `static findById`. The argument passed to `getProductsFromFile` is an arrow function (a callback) which takes `products` as a parameter.

Comment: What do you suggest  keeping the `getProductsFromFile` method and keep the cbs?

Comment: Your code does not work like OP's. It's maybe possible to remove `getProductsFromFile` but without knowing exactly what it does, it's hard to say what to replace it with.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree with it, but he might need to add more code to make it more robust and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VLAZ for figuring this one out!! There was indeed an extra space at the end of the id, which meant that there was no match, which is why the find method returned undefined!